# Slow cart, long query is updating sales_flat_quote

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, mysql, query

I'm running magento 1.7.0.2 CE and my cart is really slow. Every time I visit the cart I see this query which takes up to 30sec:

`` UPDATE sales_flat_quote SET store_id = '7', `created_a ``

Sorry, mtop doesn't show me more. I hope someone had this also and can help me.

Comment: How many stores do you have? How many products, how many existing orders, have you ever removed old quotes?

Comment: Do you still run into this problem? Then please use `mysql -u$USER -p $DATABASE -e "show full processlist"` to see the full query (replace $USER and $DATABASE with your MySQL user and the Magento database name). If not, what did you do to solve it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too old without an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that you have too many records in sales_flat_quote.
Try to mark old records inactive.

> UPDATE sales_flat_quote SET is_active=0 WHERE updated_at < '2012-01-01';

Then clear them directly in the db:

> DELETE FROM sales_flat_quote WHERE is_active=0;

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem:

Run the **MySQL** Tuner script (https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) + **MySQL** Tuning Primer Script (https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer/+download) and implement all the recommendations.

Try clearing the following directories:

```
 /var/cache/ 
 /var/locks/ 
 /var/session/
```

The above worked in my case, went from 7 - 10 second add to cart and got them down to .7 seconds.

I highly recommend you upgrade to 1.8 and take advantage of [**REDIS**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/redis-magento-ce-ee)

Actively monitor your site and tune as required, I've learned that you have to keep at it especially if you are adding more products and receiving increasing traffic.